# SubClass UIButton To retain Check Selected Using Custom TableCell in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a **TableView** and I am Using **Custom TableCell**.In TableCell I have a button. Now in TableView  I have created a **Bool Value** to check whether the Check button is Selected or not. 
The problem is When I **scroll the Table the cell get reused** so the button gets Automatically deselected.

```
    if (checkButton.selected==NO) {
        NSLog(@"ooo");
        checkButton.selected=YES;
        checkSelected=YES;
   }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Okkkkk");
       checkButton.selected=NO;
       checkSelected=NO;
    }
```

I have an idea to **Subclass UIButton with a custom Property of BOOl**.But I dont know to workout. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: once remove that checkButton.selected=YES; in if and checkButton.selected=NO; in else and check it i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a track of button selected using the array. Just set value 1 at particular index when button is selected. And set it to 0 when it's deselected.

And then while creating the cell you can check in as follows:

```
if ([[arr_Check objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    checkButton.selected=NO;
else
    checkButton.selected=YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property(nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
// DO NOT FORGET TO SYNTHESIZE MY isSelected
@end
```

since you are using a custom cell. you can just make a property CustomButton in your custom cell.

```
@interface YourCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) CustomButton *button;
@end
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

   YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellType owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = (YourCustomCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //you can add a target to your button here
    cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonState:).....
    if(cell.button.isSelected == YES)
          NSLog(@"selected");
    else
          NSLog(@"not selected");


-(void)changeButtonState:(CustomButton*)button
{
   if(button.isSelected) button.isSelected = NO;
   else                  button.isSelected = YES;
   [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: How to change over to the Image ie check off and check selected.Im getting error if i try to set as cell.checkButton.isSelected=YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i%i",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *cellSubs = cell.contentView.subviews;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < [cellSubs count] ; i++)
        {
            [[cellSubs objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UICheckBox *checkBox = [[UICheckBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44.0, 44.0)];
    checkBox.tag = indexPath.row;
    checkBox.titleLabel.tag = indexPath.section;
    [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    for (NSIndexPath *temp in selectedObjects) {
        if ([temp isEqual: indexPath]) {
            checkBox.selected = TRUE;
        }
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];

    return cell;
}

-(void)checkBoxPressed:(UICheckBox*)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:sender.titleLabel.tag];
    if (sender.selected) 
        [selectedObjects removeObject:indexPath];
    else
        [selectedObjects addObject:indexPath];
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    NSLog(@"\n\n%@",selectedObjects);
}
```

Here `selectedObjects` is a global `NSArray` and `UICheckBox` is a subClass of `UIButton`